# Ajax dynamic selectbox cakephp not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am getting this error:

> The requested address '/panel/admin/services/add_service' was not
>   found on this server

When i am submitting the form and i am getting correct values in console of my select-box.

**Jquery Code**

```
$('.edit_sub_service_data2').css('display','none');
$('#service_provider_id').change(function(){ 

   var cat_val=$(this).val();
    var hiturl= "<?php echo $this->webroot.'admin/test/get_provider?cat_id='; ?>"+cat_val;
    jQuery.ajax({
            url:hiturl,    // Send the data with your url.
            type: "GET",
            data:  {'cat_val': cat_val}, 
            dataType: "json",   
            success: function(data){ 
              $('#service_service_data_id').html("");
              $('#service_service_data_id').html(data[0]);
              }               
        });

  });
```

**PHP CODE**

```
    foreach ($category_data as $key => $value){
    $combo[] ="<option value='".$key."'>".$value."</option>";    
    }
    echo json_encode(array($combo));
    exit();
```

**FORM Submit Code**

```
  <?php echo $this->Form->input('service_data',array('class'=>'form-control','type'=>'select','id'=>'service_service_data_id')); ?>
```

This code is showing dynamic data but my form is not submitting when i submit the form just because of this drop-down in CakePhp

Comment: Question is what "The requested address '/panel/admin/services/add_service' was not found on this server" to do with javascript? You wrote this but in code is reference to admin/test/get_provider. I don't udnerstand what your question is.

Comment: I m getting this error when i submit the form just because of dynamic dropdown and when i remove the code of dynamic dropdown my form is submitting.

Comment: Request address in you ajax code is  like `admin/test/get_provider?cat_id=`     and you are getting error of `The requested address '/panel/admin/services/add_service' was not found on this server`. It's strange and ambiguous.Seems that other jQuery code are also written there and causing the issue, not this one what you shown to us

Comment: You can also look into live examples like [these](https://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax-examples/chained-dropdowns) if it helps. And always provide the CakePHP Version you are working with.